Civimail keeps boucing
I am trying to setup civimail, but every time I send an email, everything bounces with the error message: "Failed to set sender: b.13.8.qxzpjydhbxjbk2e9@example.org [SMTP: Invalid response code received from SMTP server while sending email. This is often caused by a misconfiguration in Outbound Email settings. Please verify the settings at Administer CiviCR..."
In mail accounts, if I do a save and test on the bounce processing account, it works and says connection succeeded. In Outbound email, I am using SMTP (mail stopped working) and sending a test email does work (I receive the message in my inbox).
This used to work before with the same email, but with mail() instead of SMTP. I am using Wordpress with an Ionos email.
All the other fixes I found were not relevant to my situation.
Has anyone run into this? Thank you!

Turns out since I was logged in as a user with a gmail associated with it, it was trying to send the email with my gmail email rather than my domain I had set up as the outbound email address. My custom domain email does not allow me to send emails with an email address with a different domain address.
I turned off Allow mail from logged in user in Outbound Email and everything works great now!
